# playing multiple videos at the same time

Tags: ios, ipad

Is it possible to play multiple video in a view.i have tried MPMovieMediaPlayer but only the last added video is playing,is there any other solution to play all files together.

Comment: @all i have to play atleast five videos at same time.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apple's [`AVPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer).

Comment: Keep in mind there is a limit of 4 videos playing at the same time with AVPlayer. I did not see this limit on any doc but I experienced it by myself.